# Check constraint last_name capitalized

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I make a check constraint that checks if last_name has the last 2 letters capitalized?

```
alter table clienti modify (nume_client constraint che_d check(nume_client=upper(substr(nume_client, -2, 1))));
```

I did like this, but I am getting the following error:

> 1. 00000 - "cannot validate (%s.%s) - check constraint violated"

Comment: `substr(nume_client, -2, 1) = upper(substr(nume_client, -2, 1))`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your constraint is comparing the whole name to the upper-cased second-to-last character. It's only looking at one character, because you're supplying the [third argument](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions181.htm#SQLRF06114) `substring_length` as 1. You need to check the last two characters; so you need to compare only those with the same two characters in upper-case:

```
substr(nume_client, -2) = upper(substr(nume_client, -2))
```

The error you are getting is because you have existing data which does not satisfy the constraint you are trying to add. That may be because your constraint isn't doing what you intended, as it will always return false in your original version.

If you get the same error with the modified check then you either need to remove or correct that data before you add the constraint, or use [the `novalidate` clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/clauses002.htm#i1010237):

```
check (substr(nume_client, -2) = upper(substr(nume_client, -2))) novalidate
```

Any existing constraint-violating rows will remain untouched, but you won't be able to add new rows that violate the constraint, or update existing rows to still-invalid values.

You can use your `alter table modify (column...)` syntax, or the simpler syntax Gordon Linoff showed; they do the same thing ultimately.

Answer (score 2):

You might already have records there in table, that do not pass the check constraint. If it's OK to have the check only for future transactions you can use NOVALIDATE clause to constraint. E.g.

```
CREATE TABLE names (last_name VARCHAR2(100));
--Table created
INSERT INTO names VALUES ('Rambo');
--1 row inserted
INSERT INTO names VALUES ('GatES');
--1 row inserted
alter table names add constraint chk_che_d
      check (SUBSTR(last_name,-2,1) = upper(substr(last_name, -2, 1))) NOVALIDATE;
--Table altered
INSERT INTO names VALUES ('Travolta');
--ORA-02290: check constraint (RO.CHK_CHE_D) violated
INSERT INTO names VALUES ('SkywalkER');    
--1 row inserted
```

Comment: he wants last 2 charectars to be capital, what about `INSERT INTO names VALUES ('SkywalkEr');` in your case

Answer (score 1):

This is the syntax for adding a check constraint:

```
alter table clienti add constraint chk_che_d
    check (nume_client = upper(substr(nume_client, -2, 1)));
```

I'm pretty sure the logic doesn't do anything useful (I'm pretty sure this will always return false).  But the right syntax will get you on the right path.